# opencv's ORB image tracking with c++: example?

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking, orb

My objective is tracking of keypoints in video sequences in real-time. According to my search on the net, ORB might be a good choice. However, it seems there is an important lack of documentation on the matter.

Could someone direct us to to a link on a full example on the matter, or provide us a self-contained example?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_tracking/akaze_tracking.html?highlight=orb%20akaze

Comment: @SchighSchagh The issue is that the code on that link uses extrenal libs other than opencv. So it yields the stuff bit more complicated. The best is with only opencv libs.

Comment: What are you talking about? It's purely OpenCV code.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Now I see more clearly. But please what this command means: `matches[i][0].distance < nn_match_ratio * matches[i][1].distance`?

Comment: That is the ratio test. Instead of an absolute threshold on match distance to see if a match is good, it is usually more robust to compare the closest match against the second closest match to see if they are different enough. So if some query yields two matches that are (almost) the same distance apart, then it's likely that either (a) the query matched multiple things well in which case it's not a very discriminative keypoint and should be discarded, or (b) it matched multiple things poorly and should be discarded. I believe David Lowe first proposed the method in his SIFT work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html), or read the paper:

Ethan Rublee, Vincent Rabaud, Kurt Konolige, Gary R. Bradski: ORB: An efficient alternative to SIFT or SURF. ICCV 2011: 2564-2571

Comment: It is in Python and dos not enclose tracking.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mistook the title.